Help with doing a Feynman 1-loop integral related to $\langle T_{++}\rangle$ in string theory
The goal is to compute the 1-loop integral, which is given equal to:
$$\int{\frac{d^2l}{2\pi}\frac{l_{+}(l_++q_+)}{l^2(l+q)^2}}=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{q_+}{q_{-}}.\tag{3.31}$$
The above integral represents the contribution of a loop in a Feynman diagram in the calculation of a component of energy-momentum tensor
$$\langle T_{++}\rangle$$
in string theory. Specifically, we are working in a two-dimensional field theory with Minkowski worldsheet coordinates. The calculation is formulated using light-cone coordinates, defined as:
$$\xi^\pm=\xi^0\pm \xi^1.$$
Its given in the reference [1] that the integral (3.31) is easily performed using standard dimensional regularization formulas.
Question:

In dimensional regularization, we generalize the spacetime dimension to $D=2-\epsilon\ $. Should we convert the coordinates back to general coordinates and then to Euclidean space before performing the integral, or can we directly use the dimensional regularization formulas within the light-cone coordinate system?

[1] TASI '88 lectures by Curt Callan and Lárus Thorlacius, page 31.

Which sign convention for the Minkowski metric?

negative for time

https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html. This reference is available here. Sigma models and string theory

Hi @Aleena Grace Tojan. On what grounds did you determine the conventions for the world-sheet metric and the light-cone coordinates?

Its mentioned in the page 30 of ref[1] that they are using minkowski signature

TL;DR: On one hand, the dimensional regularization relies on an Euclidean (E) integration region; while on the other hand, the indices can refer to either Minkowskian (M) or Euclidean (E) signature by using pertinent Wick rotation connection formulas.
Using dimensional regularization eq. (3.31) becomes$^1$
$$ \begin{align} \int_E\!\frac{d^d\ell}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}& 
\frac{\ell_+(\ell+q)_+}{\ell^2(\ell+q)^2}\cr 
~\stackrel{(14.9)}{=}&
\int_E\!\frac{d^d\ell}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_0^1\!dx 
\frac{\ell_+(\ell+q)_+}{[(1-x)\ell^2+x(\ell+q)^2)]^2}\cr
~=~&\int_0^1\!dx\int_E\!\frac{d^d\ell}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} 
\frac{\ell_+(\ell+q)_+}{[\ell^2 +2xq\cdot\ell +xq^2]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{\ell^{\prime}=\ell+xq}{=}&
\int_0^1\!dx\int_E\!\frac{d^d\ell^{\prime}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} 
\frac{(\ell^{\prime}-xq)_+(\ell^{\prime}+(1-x)q)_+}{[\ell^{\prime 2} +D]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{(62.18)}{=}&\int_0^1\!dx\int_E\!\frac{d^d\ell^{\prime}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} 
\frac{\ell^{\prime 2}\overbrace{\gamma_{++}}^{=0}/d-x(1-x)(q_+)^2}{[\ell^{\prime 2} +D]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{(14.27)}{=}&-(q_+)^2
\int_0^1\! dx~x(1-x)\frac{(2\pi)^{d/2}\Gamma(2-d/2)}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\Gamma(2)}D^{d/2-2}\cr
~\stackrel{d=2}{=}&-\frac{(q_+)^2}{2q^2}~=~-\frac{q_+}{4\gamma^{+-}q_-}
,\end{align} \tag{3.31}$$
where we have defined
$$   D~:=~x(1-x)q^2 \tag{14.14}$$
in close analogy with the approach of Ref. 2. So the superficially logarithmically UV divergent 1-loop diagram (3.31) is actually finite.
References:

C.G. Callan &  L. Thorlacius, Sigma models & string theory, TASI '88 lectures; Section 3.3 eq. (3.31). The preprint is available from D. Tong's string theory page here.

M. Srednicki, QFT, 2007; Chapter 14. A prepublication draft PDF file is available here.



$^1$ Footnotes:

Many string theory textbooks have $\gamma_{+-}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\gamma^{+-}=-2$, cf. e.g. D. Tong p.32 eq. (2.9).

Comparing with e.g. eq. (2.25), there appears to be no implicit $\sqrt{|\gamma|}$ factor in the volume element $d^2\xi$ notation of Ref. 1. However be aware that many string theory textbooks have an implicit factor 2 in $d^2\xi$, cf. e.g. D. Tong p.63.

Wick rotation of the volume element in momentum space yields
$$ \int_M\!d^d\ell\ldots ~=~i\int_E\!d^d\ell\ldots.\tag{14.15-16}$$



To evaluate the $l_+l_+$ term I used the dimensional regularization formula $\int{\frac{d^Dl}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{l_\mu l_\nu}{(l^2+a^2)^n}}=\delta_{\mu\nu}A(a,n,D)$,A is some gamma function dependent term and using this does'nt give me zero

The above Kronecker delta should be a metric tensor component.


But when I derive that integral result following the reference "Field Theory : A modern Primer" By P Ramond on appendix B I got a delta  https://dokumen.pub/field-theory-a-modern-primer-2ndnbsped-0201157721.html.


When we wick rotate should'nt 2. the light cone coordinates get changed to complex coordinates and 3. the integral becomes complex integration


Ramond implicitly assumes that the metric tensor  component is the Kronecker delta. 2. Yes.


Thank you Sir. I got it. That $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ was actually $\delta^{\sigma}{\mu}g{\sigma\nu}$
